# populate combobox with java script

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, dojo, dijit.form

i am write some code for cascading drop down with dojo ajax first drop down is static and second one is fetch the data from servlet .. i am using the dijit.form.ComboBox for make dropdown. Dojo provide the Store property in which he store the data and then put it into combobox. in servlet i through the array list to ajax function .. in ajax function i separate the array with comma and strore in variable and then store in the dojo's store property But i am not able to populate the whole string .. it populate only the last value of the string i am using following code

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dojo/dijit/themes/claro/document.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
        <script src='dojo/dojo/dojo.js' data-dojo-config=' parseOnLoad: true'></script>
        <script>



            require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/ComboBox","dijit/form/TextBox"]);

      function abc(){    

          var j = document.getElementById('state').value
          dojo.xhrPost({
    // The URL to request
    url: "populate",   //servlet name
    timeout :  3000 ,
    content: {
        username: dojo.byId("state").value

    },

    load: function(result) {    // the value in result is like=[Abas Store, Accounts ]

    require([
    "dojo/ready", "dojo/store/Memory", "dijit/form/ComboBox"
], function(ready, Memory, ComboBox){

     var ss=result.split(",");

     var i;
     for (i=1;i< ss.length ;i++){


    var stateStore = new Memory({

        data: [ {name:ss[i], id: ss[i]}  ]
    });
     }

    ready(function(){
        var comboBox = new ComboBox({
            id: "stateSelect",
           name:"select",
            value: "Select",
            store: stateStore,
            searchAttr: "name"
        }, "stateSelect");
    });
});

      }
});
      }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="claro">

     <select data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ComboBox" id="state" name="state"  onchange="abc();">
    <option selected >Andaman Nicobar</option>
    <option>Andhra Pradesh</option>        
 <option>Tripura</option>
 <option>Uttar Pradesh</option>
 <option>Uttaranchal</option>
 <option>West Bengal</option>

</select>
        <input id="stateSelect"  >
                   </select>


    </body>
</html>
```

please give me solution .. to populate all the value in combobox which is i get from array list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are building the store in the for loop.  Instead, you should build the data array that gets passed into the MemoryStore constructor.

```
require(["dojo/store/Memory", "dijit/form/ComboBox", "dojo/ready"], 
    function(Memory, ComboBox, ready){

        ready(function) {

           dojo.connect(dijit.byId('state'), 'onChange', function() {

               var stateSelect = dijit.byId('stateSelect');
               if (!stateSelect) {
                   stateSelect = new ComboBox({
                     id: "stateSelect",
                     name:  "select",
                     value: "Select...",
                     searchAttr: "name"
                   }, "stateSelect");
               }

               var ss = 'Abas Store, Accounts';
               ss = ss.split(',');

               var data = [];
               dojo.forEach(ss, function(item, idx) {
                   data.push({
                       id: idx,
                       name: item                    
               });
               stateSelect.set('store', new Memory({data: data}));

          }); // dojo.connect
       }); // ready     
}); // require
```

​

The working example is at http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/DLNNc/

Comment: Thank you Craig Swing .. it's working but , whenever i change the first dropdown the value other combobox (which is populate from database) is not updated it shows the previews data....

Comment: it shows me error "Tried to register widget with id==stateSelect but that id is already registered""

Comment: This error means that you are creating two widgets with the same id.  You cannot do this.

Comment: i am creating cascading dropdown if 1st dropdown is change then 2nd dropdown is also change .. so that second drop down is again get the value .. that's why it shows the error .. so how i flush combobox memory when 1st drop down is change

Comment: comboBox2.set('store', newStore);

Comment: thanx craig .. where i use that "comboBox2.set('store', newStore);" please help me

Comment: i works fine ... but one problem in it .. that is it shows the previews selected value .. like in first time when i change  1st combobox then 2nd combobox is nil and when i change the 1 st combobox value second time then in 2nd combobox it show me the previews selected value , eg by default my 1st  combobox is filled and 2nd one is blank , when i select 1st  combobox value to asia 2nd  combobox is blank , and 2nd time when i change the 1st  combobox to europe in 2nd  combobox it shows me the asia's result......

Comment: thanx Craig Swing ,, but where i put that ..?

Comment: before comboBox2.set('store', newStore);

Comment: but comboBox2.set(('store', newStore); is not available in code which is give by u...

Comment: i don't understand .. will u please give me the code to do that.. it's populate the combo box second attempt and with wrong value (the previews selected valuse )